# tensor product of two matrices over different commutative rings

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

I am now reading Nicolas Bourbaki Elements of Mathematics, Algebra I, Chapters 1-3, but meet a question.  Assume that $k$ is a field, from the example (1) on Page 463 in this book, we can easily get the the following k-algebra isomorphism $M_{n}(k)\otimes M_{m}(k)\cong M_{nm}(k),$ where n and m are two positive integers. In the following I want to try to generalize it. We assume   $B_1$ and $B_2$ are two commutative k-algebras, my question is the following: Does we have the following k-algebra isomorphism?
$$M_{n}(B_1)\otimes M_{m}(B_2)\cong M_{nm}(B_1\otimes B_2).$$

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! In Math.SE, while asking questions, please tell what you tried and where you're stuck, this'll encourage others to help you, otherwise your question may be flagged and closed.

Comment: Yes, and there is no need to assume that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are commutative or that $k$ is a field.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, Thank you very much! The main reason that I put the restrictions on $B_1$ and $B_2$ such that they are commutative is that In the example in Bourbaki's book, they always consider the matrix algebras over a single commutative ring $C$, so I want to know that if we also have the similar isomorphism over two different commutative rings $B_1$ and $B_2$. But I am not sure whether it is right if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are not commutative.